# Electric or electrical

Tags: word-meaning, difference, singular-vs-plural

Someone told me that the word electric is used for singular nouns and electrical for plural nouns like we can't say electric goods but electrical goods . Is that true if it's not please write the proof because I will send it to her

Comment: Electrical eels?

Comment: I hate to nit pick, but the other two answers are discussing the usage of the two words. The OP specifically asked about using one with singular and the other with plural nouns and to provide proof or counter examples to back the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try **electric cars** and **electrical distribution box** as counter examples. Both are common phrases and there are many more. Just google each word for other examples such as:
**electric light bulb[s]** both singular and plural.
**electrical engineer[ing]**

Answer (score 0):

**Electric** is used to talk about machines/devices which use electricity.

electric motor, electric cooker, electric toothbrush, electric blanket, electric car, electric kettle, electric light

**Electrical** is also used about machines/devices which use electricity.

We use 'electrical' before 'equipment', 'appliance' etc.

electrical equipment, electrical appliances, electrical devices, electrical goods.

'**Electrical**' is also used to talk about people or organizations connected with  the production of electricity.

electrical engineer.

Answer (score 0):

While [major dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/electrical) say that they mean the same thing, but in common usage, there's a difference.

We normally use "electric" to refer to simple things that directly use electricity, like electric cables, electric outlets, plugs, switches, volt flashlights, power tools, fuses and so on.

We normally use "electrical" to refer to more complex devices that happen to be powered by electricity, but don't simply act on the electricity, like garage door openers, USB flash drives, computer screens and so on -- just about anything that uses circuit board logic is considered "electronic" rather than "electric".